# Receiving multiple times from a single client. I can only recieve from the client once and then every response is NULL

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I want the server to send a OTP (one-time password) to the client. Then the client sends the password back to the server it was received from, and if they match then furthur conversation happens.

This code is for server side:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Create a listen socket
    int listen_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Create Local Server address and initialise family, port number, IP address
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(10000);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // bind listen socket with local server address
    bind(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    // listen for a connection
    listen(listen_socket, 10);

    // accept a connection to create socket for data exchange
    int data_exchange_socket = accept(listen_socket, NULL, NULL);

    //--------------------------------- LOGIC ----------------------------------------
    //OTP for authentication
    char* server_password = "vikas@hplap";

    // send OTP to client
    send(data_exchange_socket, server_password, strlen(server_password), 0);

    // recieve OTP
    char* client_password;
    recv(data_exchange_socket, client_password, 50, 0);

    // authenticate
    if(strcmp(server_password, client_password) == 0)
    {
        // Correct OTP sent by client
        char* server_verdict = "Correct";
        send(data_exchange_socket, server_verdict, strlen(server_verdict), 0);

        // get client message
        char* client_message;
        recv(data_exchange_socket, client_message, 50, 0);
        printf("Client Message: %s\n", client_message);

        //server respond with hello
        char* server_response = "Hello, Press any key to exit...";
        send(data_exchange_socket, server_response, strlen(server_response), 0);
        printf("Data sent\n"); // This doesn't execute
    }
    else
    {
        // handle wrong OTP by client
        char* server_response = "Incorrect OTP entered!";
        send(data_exchange_socket, server_response, strlen(server_response), 0);
    }

    // shut down server
    printf("Server Closed :)\n"); // This is also not executed
    close(listen_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code for the client side:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // create socket for data exchange
    int data_exchange_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // create remote server address
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(10000);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // try to connect with server
    int status=connect(data_exchange_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if(status==-1)
    {
        printf("\n connection error.....");
    }

    // recieve OTP from server
    char* otp;
    recv(data_exchange_socket, otp, 50, 0);

    // send server the otp recieved
    send(data_exchange_socket, otp, strlen(otp), 0);

    // recieve server message
    char* server_verdict;
    recv(data_exchange_socket, server_verdict, 50, 0);


    if(strcmp(server_verdict, "Correct") == 0)
    {
        // Send "Hi" to server
        char* client_response = "Hi";
        send(data_exchange_socket, client_response, strlen(client_response), 0);

        // recieve server message
        char* server_message;
        recv(data_exchange_socket, server_message, 50, 0);
        printf("Server Message: %s\n", server_message);
    }
    close(data_exchange_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

I think it is because maybe we can only receive once with one data_exchange_socket. But then I didn't find it true for the client code.

Please tell me if the above is true.  I cannot understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: There are some big flaws in your code. 1. `char* client_password;` that's an uninitialised pointer. Writing to it is undefined behaviour.  2. The terminating NUL is not sent so the receiver doesn't get a valid C string and must not treat it as a string. 3. TCP is a streaming protocol so it cannot be assumed that each `recv` will receive everything from a "matching" `send`.

Comment: @kaylum So should i keep recv statements in loops ?

Comment: For the third issue? Firstly you absolutely must always check the return value of functions, `recv` in this case. And then yes you need to loop receiving until the "expected" data has been received. To determine when the data has been received requires data "framing" - that is, the start and end of each msg. In this case, could use the NUL character as a framing byte.

Comment: @kaylum Thanku for such a fast response. Also is there something like we can only receive once with one data exchange socket created by accept function and we must create new socket with accept function for every recv from client. Even for multiple recv from same client ?

Comment: Absolutely not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling your string transmissions correctly.  You are not framing your strings in such a way, either by sending the string length or the null terminator, so that the receiver can know when to stop reading each string.  And you are not allocating any memory for `recv()` to read into.  Or accounting for the fact that TCP is a stream so there is no 1:1 relationship between `send()` and `recv()`, partial sends/reads are possible.

Try something more like this instead:

Common:

```c
int sendString(int sock, const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    int numSent;

    while (len > 0)
    {
        numSent = send(sock, str, len, 0);
        if (numSent < 0)
            return -1;
        str += numSent;
        len -= numSent;
    }

    return 0;
}

int recvString(int sock, char **msg)
{
    size_t len = 0, cap = 0, size;
    char ch, *newmsg;
    int numRecv;

    *msg = NULL;

    do
    {
        numRecv = recv(sock, &ch, 1, 0);
        if (numRecv <= 0)
        {
            free(*msg);
            *msg = NULL;
            return numRecv;
        }

        if (len == cap)
        {
            size = (ch == '\0') ? (len + 1) : (len + 50);

            newmsg = realloc(*msg, size);
            if (newmsg == NULL)
            {
                free(*msg);
                *msg = NULL;
                return -1;
            }

            memcpy(newmsg, *msg, len);
            *msg = newmsg;
            cap = size;
        }

        (*msg)[len] = ch;
        ++len;
    }
    while (ch != '\0');

    return 1;
}
```

Alternatively:

```c
int sendRaw(int sock, void *data, size_t size)
{
    char *pdata = data;
    int numSent;

    while (size > 0)
    {
        numSent = send(sock, pdata, size, 0);
        if (numSent < 0)
            return -1;
        pdata += numSent;
        size -= numSent;
    }

    return 0;
}

int recvRaw(int sock, void *data, size_t size)
{
    char *pdata = data;
    int numRecv;

    while (size > 0)
    {
        numRecv = recv(sock, pdata, size, 0);
        if (numRecv <= 0)
            return numRecv;
        pdata += numRecv;
        size -= numRecv;
    }

    return 1;
}

int sendUInt32(int sock, uint32_t val)
{
    val = htonl(val);
    return sendRaw(sock, &val, sizeof(val));
}

int recvUInt32(int sock, uint32_t *val)
{
    int res = recvRaw(sock, val, sizeof(*val));
    if (res <= 0) return res;
    *val = ntohl(*val);
    return 1;
}

int sendString(int sock, const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (sendUInt32(sock, len) < 0) return -1;
    return sendRaw(sock, str, len);
}

int recvString(int sock, char **msg)
{
    *msg = NULL;

    uint32_t len;
    int res = recvUInt32(sock, &len);
    if (res <= 0)
        return res;

    char *newmsg = malloc(len + 1);
    if (newmsg == NULL)
        return -1;

    res = recvRaw(sock, newmsg, len);
    if (res <= 0)
    {
        free(newmsg);
        return res;
    }

    newmsg[len] = '\0';
    *msg = newmsg;

    return 1;
}
```

Then you can do this:

Server:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "Common.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Create a listen socket
    int listen_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listen_socket < 0)
    {
        perror("Error creating listening socket");
        return -1;
    }

    // Create Local Server address and initialize family, port number, IP address
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(10000);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // bind listen socket with local server address
    if (bind(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error binding listening socket");
        close(listen_socket);
        return -1;
    }

    // listen for a connection
    if (listen(listen_socket, 10) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error opening listening socket");
        close(listen_socket);
        return -1;
    }

    // accept a connection to create socket for data exchange
    int data_exchange_socket = accept(listen_socket, NULL, NULL);
    if (data_exchange_socket < 0)
    {
        perror("Error accepting a client");
        close(listen_socket);
        return -1;
    }

    //--------------------------------- LOGIC ----------------------------------------
    //OTP for authentication

    // send OTP to client
    if (sendString(data_exchange_socket, "vikas@hplap") < 0)
    {
        perror("Error sending password to client");
        close(data_exchange_socket);
        close(listen_socket);
        return 0;
    }

    // receive OTP
    char* client_password;
    int res = recvString(data_exchange_socket, &client_password);
    if (res <= 0)
    {
        if (res < 0)
            perror("Error receiving password from client");
        else
            printf("Disconnected while receiving password from client\n");
        close(data_exchange_socket);
        close(listen_socket);
        return 0;
    }

    // authenticate
    int res = strcmp(server_password, client_password);
    free(client_password);
    if (res == 0)
    {
        // Correct OTP sent by client
        if (sendString(data_exchange_socket, "Correct") < 0)
        {
            perror("Error sending verdict to client");
            close(data_exchange_socket);
            close(listen_socket);
            return 0;
        }

        // get client message
        char* client_message;
        res = recvString(data_exchange_socket, &client_message);
        if (res <= 0)
        {
            if (res < 0)
                perror("Error receiving message from client");
            else
                printf("Disconnected while receiving message from client\n");
            close(data_exchange_socket);
            close(listen_socket);
            return 0;
        }

        printf("Client Message: %s\n", client_message);
        free(client_message);

        //server respond with hello
        if (sendString(data_exchange_socket, "Hello, Press any key to exit...") < 0)
        {
            perror("Error sending message to client");
            close(data_exchange_socket);
            close(listen_socket);
            return 0;
        }

        printf("Data sent\n"); // This doesn't execute
    }
    else
    {
        // handle wrong OTP by client
        if (sendString(data_exchange_socket, "Incorrect OTP entered!") < 0)
        {
            perror("Error sending verdict to client");
            close(data_exchange_socket);
            close(listen_socket);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // shut down server
    printf("Server Closed :)\n"); // This is also not executed

    close(data_exchange_socket);
    close(listen_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h>

#include "Common.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // create socket for data exchange
    int data_exchange_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (data_exchange_socket < 0)
    {
        perror("Error creating socket");
        return -1;
    }

    // create remote server address
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(10000);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    // try to connect with server
    if (connect(data_exchange_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error connecting to server");
        close(data_exchange_socket);
        return -1;
    }

    // recieve OTP from server
    char* otp;
    int res = recvString(data_exchange_socket, &otp);
    if (res <= 0)
    {
        if (res < 0)
            perror("Error receiving password from server");
        else
            printf("Disconnected while receiving password from server\n");
        close(data_exchange_socket);
        return -1;
    }

    // send server the otp received
    if (sendString(data_exchange_socket, otp) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error sending password to server");
        free(otp);
        close(data_exchange_socket);
        return -1;
    }
    free(otp);

    // receive server message
    char* server_verdict;
    res = recvString(data_exchange_socket, &server_verdict);
    if (res <= 0)
    {
        if (res < 0)
            perror("Error receiving verdict from server");
        else
            printf("Disconnected while receiving verdict from server\n");
        close(data_exchange_socket);
        return -1;
    }

    res = strcmp(server_verdict, "Correct");
    free(server_verdict);
    if (res == 0)
    {
        // Send "Hi" to server
        if (sendString(data_exchange_socket, "Hi") < 0)
        {
            perror("Error sending message to server");
            close(data_exchange_socket);
            return -1;
        }

        // recieve server message
        char* server_message;
        res = recvString(data_exchange_socket, &server_message);
        if (res <= 0)
        {
            if (res < 0)
                perror("Error receiving message from server");
            else
                printf("Disconnected while receiving message from server\n");
            close(data_exchange_socket);
            return -1;
        }

        printf("Server Message: %s\n", server_message);
        free(server_message);
    }

    close(data_exchange_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank u very much for spending time in this, i got it